# jQuery Validate: Remove element AFTER validation BEFORE submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a SVG map of a city that when clicked, creates hidden elements in a div in my form.

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate my form.

In order to make sure that the user has clicked on an area of the map, I thought to create a dummy hidden element inside where the normal hidden elements are and put the validation rule on that. I wrote my own validation rule to check for the number of hidden elements (indicating that a user has clicked somewhere on the map). That rule is this:

```
$.validator.methods.zones = function (value, element, param) {
   return ($('#search_form #zone-selectors input').length > 1); // 1 instead of 0 to account for the dummy element
};

<div id="zone-selectors">
  <input type="hidden" name="dummy">
</div>
```

However, I cannot allow that dummy element to be submitted with the rest of the form; I need to remove it AFTER the form has been validated but BEFORE the form is submitted. Naturally, I thought to use the `submitHandler` option for `validate()`:

```
// ...
submitHandler: function(form) {
   $(form).find('input[name=dummy]').remove();
   $(form).submit();
},
// ...
```

... but this seems to create an infinite loop, and my browser times-out the script.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submitHandler` needs a tweak, like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   $(form).find('input[name=dummy]').remove();
   form.submit();
}
```

Calling the jQuery [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) trigger causes validation again, and an infinite loop...you want to call the native [`.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) function here.

Comment: Now the form doesn't submit at all...? The hidden element is removed, however, so I know the `submitHandler` is being called.

Comment: @neezer - Does the form have an action? Or are you trying to submit via ajax?

Comment: @nick It has an action. I want a normal submit, not an Ajax submit.

Comment: @neezer - do you have a link to the page I can see?

Comment: @nick - Of course, as soon as I post the link I can't reproduce the problem. Looks like it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me when the above answer did not. Maybe has to do with jQuery and jQuery Validation versions.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   $('input[name=dummy]', form).remove();
   form.submit();
}
```